I was assaulted
I was assaulted and am being stalked by a former dating partner of only 8 months, he is married and I don't know why he won't leave me alone. I have tried speaking with law enforcements, courts and lawyers. He still will not stop. If I was not a virgin at the time that we dated, does the trauma I went through still protect me under Jewish law?

You've nothing to worry about re Jewish law. I hope you are able to find competent help very quickly. I don't know your situation, if you can find a Rabbi and/or Rebbetzin, or reach out to a Yoetzet. Either way don't struggle alone. I have put a couple of links in this comment if all else fails. Do not be upset that this question gets closed - it's just reflective of the fact that this site doesn't support personal questions.

Unfortunately, there is very little a Jewish court can do nowadays, as they have no jurisdiction. Discussions of Jewish law would be mostly academic. I hope Hashem gives you the support you need.
